# Can I build universal apps for iPhone and iPad with React-Native?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, react-native

Is it possible to create universal apps that work both on the iPhone and the iPad with customized for the individual devices? if so how?

Comment: There's a package for this that gives you `Display.isTablet()`: https://github.com/kkjdaniel/react-native-device-display

Comment: https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info will give you all of the device's info including a function that returns a type Bool if it's a tablet or not.